# Building custom bootable image from installed and customized FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: freebsd

I am using FreeBSD 10.1 amd64. I customized it and now i want to make a bootable image so that I can install it on any machine with usb stick. How can I make the Bootable image from the Pre- installed OS?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no easy way to do this. Your best option is to look at how official images are made (see `/usr/src/release`) and the customization that offers.